# AutoCast datatype in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, casting, azure-databricks

I am creating a parquet file from PostgresSQL and it has everything marked as varchar column. Once we have the file in ADLS, we want to cast the data type according to the data like date, integer, varchar field in Azure databricks using Python/Pyspark.Same code will be utilized by multiple file with different schema so wanted a generic process.
So wanted a method to auto cast the fileds

Comment: Create a StructType schema and then provide that schema  while reading the files. https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-structtype-and-structfield/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce and **Auto Cast** method using pyspark to **CAST** all Varchar datatypes  according to the data like Date, Integer, Varchar fields.

For example, I have created data and columns using the string data type and I have them In ADLS as **Parquet** format.

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("name", StringType(), True),
StructField("birth_date", StringType(), True),
StructField("age", StringType(), True),
StructField("score", StringType(), True)
])
data = [("John", "1990-01-01", "123", "12.34"),
("Alice", "1995-05-15", "456", "56.78")]
```

[image]

[image]

The below code will do the AUTO CAST for the datatypes **Date, Integer, Varchar**

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_date, to_timestamp, when
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType, DoubleType
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AutoCastParquet").getOrCreate()
Parquet_file_path = "abfss://folder02@dileepstorageaccount02.dfs.core.windows.net/parquet_sample.parquet"
parquet_df = spark.read.parquet(Parquet_file_path)
casting_functions = {
    "string": lambda col_name: col(col_name),  
    "date": to_date,
    "timestamp": to_timestamp,
    "integer": lambda col_name: col(col_name).cast("integer"),
    "double": lambda col_name: col(col_name).cast("double"),
}
for column_name, data_type in parquet_df.dtypes:
    if "string" in data_type.lower():
        cast_func = casting_functions.get(data_type.lower())
        if cast_func:
            parquet_df = parquet_df.withColumn(column_name, cast_func(column_name))
parquet_df = parquet_df.withColumn(
    "birth_date",
    when(
        to_date(col("birth_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd").isNotNull(),
        to_date(col("birth_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
    ).otherwise(None)
)
parquet_df = parquet_df.withColumn(
    "age",
    when(
        col("age").cast("integer").isNotNull(),
        col("age").cast("integer")
    ).otherwise(None)
)
parquet_df = parquet_df.withColumn(
    "score",
    when(
        col("score").cast("double").isNotNull(),
        col("score").cast("double")
    ).otherwise(None)
)
new_schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("birth_date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("score", DoubleType(), True)
])
parquet_df = spark.createDataFrame(parquet_df.rdd, new_schema)
parquet_df.printSchema()
display(parquet_df)
```

[image]

The above code reads a Parquet file from Azure Data Lake Storage into a Spark DataFrame, automatically identifies **StringType** columns, and casts them to their inferred data types using predefined casting functions. The resulting DataFrame, with the corrected data types.

Comment: Here you have fixed the schema. I have n number of files and each file has different schema.  I wanted a generic code that will detect the datatype from value and then create a schema. or some other approach

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV Ok let me try that for you

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV Try using the parquet_df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").parquet(Parquet_file_path)
 This option allows Spark to automatically infer the schema from the data in each Parquet file.

Comment: Yes but its reading integer value as String